# ethereum-go how to get the latest block?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, golang

I've set up a private local Ethereum node with just a genesis block I made, and I have this Go code I want to run on the private local network:

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "math/big"

        "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc"
    )

    type Block struct {
        Number *big.Int
    }

    func main() {
        // Connect the client
        client, err := rpc.Dial("http://localhost:8000")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        var lastBlock Block
        if err := client.Call(&lastBlock,
            "eth_getBlockByNumber",
            "latest"); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("can't get latest block:", err)
            return
        }

        // Print events from the subscription as they arrive.
        fmt.Println("latest block:", lastBlock.Number)
    }
```

It compiles fine, but when I run it I get this error: `can't get latest block: missing value for required argument 1`

I'm passing in `"latest"`, which is a valid argument for the RPC call according to the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call).

I tracked down the error output to [this file](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/357732a8404c9fe4d02f041d20a0d05381a3e6d1/rpc/json.go#L289) and it seems the string is getting converted to `nil` and the RPC call is failing. Does anyone know what's going on here or how to fix this weird issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work by adding a `true` parameter in `err = client.Call(&lastBlock, "eth_getBlockByNumber", "latest", true)` and changing `*bit.Int` to `string`

Like this:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc"
)

type Block struct {
    Number string
}

func main() {
  // Connect the client
  client, err := rpc.Dial("http://localhost:8000")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not create ipc client: %v", err)
  }

  var lastBlock Block
  err = client.Call(&lastBlock, "eth_getBlockByNumber", "latest", true)
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("can't get latest block:", err)
      return
  }

  // Print events from the subscription as they arrive.
  fmt.Printf("latest block: %v\n", lastBlock.Number)
}
```

The result should be in hexa (like 0x5c67)